# How to convert a data-frame' column to plot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.dates import num2date, date2num

dates_s = dates.date2num(df['Last Update'])
df.plot(kind='line',x='dates_s',y='Confirmed',color='red')
plt.show()
```

I already converted the column Last Update which contains dates using:

```
df['Last Update'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Last Update'])
```

Now when I want to plot this in the x axis to see the evolution of 'Confirmed' I get an error saying:

> KeyError: 'Last Update'
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\32466\Desktop\python\corona_analysis.py", line 79, in
>
> datess = dates.date2num(df['Last Update'])   File "C:\Users\32466\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
> line 2902, in **getitem**
> indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)   File "C:\Users\32466\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py",
> line 2891, in get_loc
> raise KeyError(key) from err KeyError: 'Last Update'

Comment: The column `Last Update` doesn't exist in your dataframe. Neither will neither will `"dates_s"`, since that's a sepatate object altogether. But I don't think that matters. You don't need to convert the column to plot it.

Comment: is it possible to plot a column from a dataframe?

Comment: Can you provide a sample for df? or how it's created. Looks like your df doesn't have the `Last Update` column. Once that's been verified, change your code to `dates_s.plot(kind='line',x='Last Update',y='Confirmed',color='red')`

Comment: Okay I think I know what the problem is but I don't know why. I used groupby on 'Last Update' using this code: 

df= df.groupby(by=[pd.Grouper('Country'),pd.Grouper(key='Last Update', freq='D')]).sum()

now it's showing in the df but when I print(df.columns) it's not there?

Comment: edit: I fixed the problem with .reset_index ! Finally got a plot thanks !! although I used df.plot()